# Vuejs Webpack build outputs several classes with the same name

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have several classes defined in individual .js files and imported in various places.

These work perfectly in the local running server, but when built for deployment each of these classes ends up with the same name: `n`.

I suspect this wouldn't be an issue normally, but I'm using these class names as object keys for some local data storage and they're stomping on each other.

Is there a way to force Webpack not to change to a variable name? Or some way to make Webpack aware that these all need to be different?

*Code example:*

```
class Custom1 extends Model {/*constructor and stuff*/}
class Custom2 extends Model {/*constructor and stuff*/}
class Custom3 extends Model {/*constructor and stuff*/}
```

Then using the class names like this:

```
var myDataObject = {};
myDataObject[Custom1.name] = 'value 1';
myDataObject[Custom2.name] = 'value 2';
myDataObject[Custom3.name] = 'value 3';
```

Which produces, as expected:

```
{
    'Custom1': 'value 1',
    'Custom2': 'value 2',
    'Custom3': 'value 3',
}
```

However, once built and deployed, it's just

```
{
    'n': 'value 3
}
```

Logging the name of each class always results in 'n':

```
console.log(Custom1.name); //'Custom1' locally, 'n' after packing
console.log(Custom2.name); //'Custom2' locally, 'n' after packing
console.log(Custom3.name); //'Custom3' locally, 'n' after packing
```

Comment: I think you should post some example code. If the webpack build thinks it is the same variable name then check if the variable is public or private (or make it private). If you mean classnames, like css style classes then you should explain with some code.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg updated with code example but there's really not much to it beyond the OP...